# Continue chaining on a many to many relationship using eloquent

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I have a many to many relationship between User and Subject. The following code fetches all subjects associated with that authenticated user.

```
$chosensubject = Auth::User()->usersubject;
```

What I would like to do is take only 4 subjects and no more. Is this possible without using the query builder? For example I would like my code to look something like this:

```
$chosensubject = Auth::User()->usersubject->take(4)->get();
```

I think this may be possible using Laravel 5 however I am using Laravel version 4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
$chosensubject = Auth::User()->usersubject->take(4)->get();
```

To this:

```
$chosensubject = Auth::User()->usersubject()->take(4)->get();
```

This is the same with Laravel 4 and 5.